# WSO2 BRS to ESB

Tags: wso2, business-rules, wso2-esb

newbie on ESB and BRS here.

### Below message was displayed in WSO2 download page for BRS:

IMPORTANT NOTICE
The WSO2 Business Rules Server (WSO2 BRS) was created as a mechanism to host standalone business rules services. We no longer believe it is well suited for others to use directly, and as such it will no longer be available for download.
We currently have the ability to execute business rules within WSO2 ESB, and we encourage you to continue to use the WSO2 ESB to create business rules services.
If you are currently using WSO2 BRS as a standalone product please contact us

### We will of course support it as needed or help you migrate to the right higher level product.

How can I implement this example I saw on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-D2Hgdrzs8 using WSO2 ESB because BRS is no longer promoted.

I don't know also if I got it right, but my understanding is that the mediators like rule mediator is the best fit solution to implement business rules in ESB now. Am I right?

I hope you can help me how to translate the video tutorial from using BRS to ESB in WSO2, or at least if you know some good sites to read and use as reference, then I am happy to visit them as well.

Thank you in advance.